# Simplifying array results in Swift

Tags: swift

I am trying to obtain an array of Facebook IDs from a Graph Request. So far I have used the following code:

```
    if let userData = result as? [String:Any] {
        let id = userData["data"]
        print(id)
    }
```

However, the result is still too messy for me to work with. For example, the print statement gives me:

```
    Optional(<__NSArrayI 0x1c42285c0>(
    {
        id = aaaaaaa;
    },
    {
        id = bbbbbbb;
    }
    )
    )
```

How can I further clean up the result to get a simple array?
The desired result looks like: `[aaaaaaa, bbbbbbb,...]`.

also, printing userData shows:

```
    ["summary": {
"total_count" = 867;
    }, "data": <__NSArrayI 0x1c0429260>(
    {
id = aaaaaaa;
    },
    {
id = bbbbbbb;
    }
    )
    , "paging": {
cursors =     {
    after = //a long nasty thing
    before = //another long nasty thing
};
    }]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `flatMap` for simplifying the result.

```
if let idArray = userData[data] as? [[String: Any]] {
    let ids = idArray.flatMap { $0["id"] as? String }
    print(ids) //[aaaaaaa, bbbbbbb,...]
}
```

Comment: I got a value of nil

Comment: yes it is. However, I changed it to let idArray = userData["data"] as? [String: Any]

Comment: Cannot subscript a value of type '[[String : Any]]' with an index of type 'String'

Comment: looks like you nailed it!